# Easier way to create a list from data table in R

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
dt <- data.table(x = c("Allen", "Brandon", "Allen", "Brandon", "Chris", "Chris"),
                 y = c("orange", "red", "blue", "gold", "black", "white"))

print(dt)
#        x      y
#1   Allen orange
#2 Brandon    red
#3   Allen   blue
#4 Brandon   gold
#5   Chris  black
#6   Chris  white
```

And I would like to transpose it into a list format using `dt$x` for the list breaks:

```
print(dt2)
[[1]]
[1] "orange" "blue"  

[[2]]
[1] "red"  "gold"

[[3]]
[1] "black" "white"
```

The way that I am currently doing this is with the following function below, but I'm looking for a more efficient solution to create the list, as my real data set contains 100k~ rows.

```
dt.f <- function(a) {
  j <- dt[x == a, ]
  j2 <- as.vector(j$y)
}

dt2 <- do.call("list", lapply(unique(dt$x), function(a) dt.f(a)))
```

Comment: You could alternately do `dt[, .(ys = .(y)), by=x]` (a different format).

Comment: @Frank and of course `dt[, .(ys = .(y)), by=x][,ys]` gives exactly what OP wants. Or even simpler `dt[, .(.(y)), x][,V1]`

Comment: @dww Thanks, yeah. I guess that might be less efficient than `unname(with(dt, split(y,x)))`, which seems more direct, if that's the output the OP really insists on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `split` function:

```
dt2 <- split(dt, dt$x)
```

You can manipulate `d2` then to just extract the second part of the lists (the `y`) if that's all you want.

Comment: `split(dt2[,y], dt2[,x])` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `split.data.table` (available from 1.9.8+):

```
split(dt, by="x", keep.by=FALSE)
```

if you want to get vector instead of single column data.table you can wrap into `lapply(., unlist)`:

```
lapply(split(dt, by="x", keep.by=FALSE), unlist, use.names=FALSE)
```